# why WordPress use "bigint(20)" if result with "bigint(1)" and mediumint(1) is the same? (for field_ID is best mediumint(1) vs mediumint(20) ?)

Tags: mysql

in tables WP_options, WP_users, WP_comments the programmers used "bigint(20)"

but when I create the tables p1 and p2 I obtain the same result in QUERYS:

```
CREATE TABLE `prueba` (
  `id` mediumint(9) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `n1` mediumint(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `n2` mediumint(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `prueba`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `prueba`
  MODIFY `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=4;
COMMIT;


CREATE TABLE `prueba2` (
  `id` mediumint(20) NOT NULL,
  `n1` mediumint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `n2` mediumint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `prueba2`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `prueba2`
  MODIFY `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=4;
COMMIT;

INSERT INTO `prueba` VALUES (NULL, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO `prueba` VALUES (NULL, 16777215, 16777215);
INSERT INTO `prueba2` VALUES (NULL, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO `prueba2` VALUES (NULL, 16777215, 16777215);
```

then why is best id mediumint(1) vs mediumint(20) ?

eat more disk mediumint(20)?

is more speed select from mediumint(1)?

Answer (score 1):

You should ignore the numbers following all INT, MEDIUMINT, BIGINT, SMALLINT, TINYINT. They don't mean anything useful.

It does not affect the storage size. It does not affect the performance. It does not affect the range of values you can store in the column.

In MySQL 8.0, they have finally removed the argument to the integer types by default.

The arguments to DECIMAL or CHAR or VARCHAR are different. Those have functional purpose for determining the size and range of values you can store.

Comment: thanks, then is ok define FOR A "column_visits_ID" int(1) ? (millions of access to website as Youtube)

Comment: Using `INT` with any argument will be a 32-bit signed integer, and it can store any value in the range supported by that type. If you doubt, then test it.

Comment: many thanks master @Bill Karwin, and congratulations: **https://pragprog.com/titles/bksap1/sql-antipatterns-volume-1/**